# An error occurred while starting the kernel. Spyder, Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

I'm using Spyder 5.0.5, Python 3.8.8, Tensorflow 2.5.0

Below is the full error:

```
2021 11:44:48.064430: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

2021 11:44:50.029862: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance‑critical operations: AVX AVX2

To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021 11:44:50.033329: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] 
Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll

2021 11:44:50.077821: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.83GHz coreCount: 22 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2021 11:44:50.077845: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll

2021 11:44:50.083971: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll

2021 11:44:50.083989: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll

2021 11:44:50.087030: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll

2021 11:44:50.088058: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll

2021 11:44:50.094993: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll

2021 11:44:50.097459: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll

2021 11:44:50.097956: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

2021 11:44:50.098033: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

2021 11:44:50.459069: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021 11:44:50.459095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264] 0 
2021 11:44:50.459101: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0: N 
2021 11:44:50.459239: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3987 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)

2021 11:44:54.825675: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.83GHz coreCount: 22 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2021 11:44:54.825714: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021 11:44:54.825852: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.83GHz coreCount: 22 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2021 11:44:54.825876: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021 11:44:54.825906: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021 11:44:54.825912: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264] 0 
2021 11:44:54.825916: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0: N 
2021 11:44:54.825980: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3987 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021 11:44:55.241511: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:126] Profiler session initializing.
2021 11:44:55.241527: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:141] Profiler session started.
2021 11:44:55.241544: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1611] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2021 11:44:55.242087: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_112.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_112.dll not found
2021 11:44:55.242495: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cupti.dll'; dlerror: cupti.dll not found
2021 11:44:55.242512: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1661] function cupti_interface_‑>Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
2021 11:44:55.242527: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:159] Profiler session tear down.
2021 11:44:55.242539: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1752] function cupti_interface_‑>Finalize()failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
2021 11:44:55.326353: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021 11:44:57.591741: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
```

Comment: You need update the anaconda try `conda update anaconda`. Thanks!